# Telebot. Как сделать чтобы пользователь смог нажать кнопку один раз в сутки?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Делаю телеграм бота на Python и нужно сделать чтобы пользователь смог нажать на
кнопку(KeyboardButton) один раз в 24 часа. И вот вопрос: как это реализовать?

Comment: Запускайте таймер на 24ч после нажатия, и пока таймер работает, не давайте нажимать снова.

Comment: Записывайте время нажатия в общий словарь, где ключ это айди юзера, а значение время нажатия. И потом просто делайте проверку.